# ORDER BY RAND() in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-order-by

I want use `ORDER BY RAND()` query mysql. But I have some question want to ask.

my mysql table 'image' like:

```
id | image | width | height |
1  | 1.jpg | 640   | 480    |
2  | 2.jpg | 800   | 600    |
3  | 3.jpg | 480   | 600    |
4  | 4.jpg | 720   | 480    |
5  | 5.jpg | 600   | 800    |
6  | 6.jpg | 1024  | 768    |
7  | 7.jpg | 768   | 1024   |
8  | 8.jpg | 800   | 600    |
9  | 9.jpg | 720   | 560    |
10 | 10.jpg| 800   | 600    |
```

I need do a mysql query `ORDER BY RAND()` print `5 images`, the orders are:

`first: width >= 720 and height >= 560 , 1 image(this may be width < height)`

`second: width > height, 2 images.(left the first 1 image, do the rest 9 images ORDER BY RAND())`

`third: width >= 640, 2 images.(left above 3 images, do the rest 7 images ORDER BY RAND())`

all the 5 images no repeat. My mind are confused now, need a help.

Comment: My mind is confused too after reading your description..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Well, if I understand your question correctly you want to do something like

```
(SELECT image FROM tab WHERE(first) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)
UNION
(SELECT image FROM tab WHERE(second) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2)
UNION
(SELECT image FROM tab WHERE(third) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 2)
```

In the each WHERE clause replace the `first`, `second` and `third` with correct constraints...

Comment: Not exactly the (overly complicated) thing that OP asks for but still gets my +1

Comment: UNION the same table, remove duplicate result, that's a just method. this is what i did not think of. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT id
FROM
  ( ( SELECT MIN(q) AS q,id
      FROM
        ( (SELECT 1 AS q, id FROM image WHERE(first) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 1)
        UNION ALL
          (SELECT 2,id FROM image WHERE(second) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 3)
        ) AS tmp2
      GROUP BY id
      ORDER BY MIN(q)
      LIMIT 3
    )
  UNION ALL
    (SELECT 3, id FROM image WHERE(third) ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 5)
  ) AS tmp3
GROUP BY id
ORDER BY MIN(q)
LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 1):

You can order by multiple different values.

You can even order by the result of a boolean expression where true is treated as a higher value than false (so DESC gives you true first.)

You just put a comma between each ORDER BY clause.

Here is your example:

```
select * 
from foo 
ORDER BY
( width >= 729 AND height > 560 ) DESC,
( width > height ) DESC,
( WIDTH >= 640 ) DESC,
RAND()
```

Good luck.

Comment: so how to control the `LIMIT` thing? if `( width >= 729 AND height > 560 ) LIMIT 1`, `( width > height ) LIMIT 2`,`( WIDTH >= 640 ) LIMIT 2` ?

Comment: LIMIT 2 at the end after RAND()  you cannot do the if with the limit. but you can define limit value in the logic of your application.